# Running PyCharm project from command line

Tags: python, python-2.7, pycharm

I am trying to deploy my project to a server and run it there. 
When I try to start a script from command line it shows errors 
when importing scripts that are in parrent directories.

I made the project (python 2.7.10) using PyCharm and it is spread out into multiple directories.
The folders look something like this:

project/dir/subdir/main_dir/script1.py

```
from dir.subdir.other_dir.script2 import *  //gives error here
```

project/dir/subdir/other_dir/script2.py

```
def my_function():
    //do something
```

I run the script by going to the main_dir and running: python script1.py

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are running your script from the `main_dir`, that means when running your Python command, your relative reference is `main_dir`. So your imports are with respect to `main_dir` being your root.

This means if we take your script1 for example, your import should look like this:

```
from other_dir.script2 import *
```

Chances are your PyCharm project root is actually set to run from

```
project/
```

Which is why your references work within PyCharm.

What I suggest you do is, if your server is supposed to run within `main_dir` then you should re-configure PyCharm so that its execution root is the same in order to remove this confusion.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution to this problem in my case was to add a **main**.py script in the root of the python project which triggers the program.

project/__main__.py:

```
from dir.subdir.other_dir.script2 import *  //doesn't give errors
```

This means that when calling the program from the terminal the workspace would be correct and every inclusion of script would have the folders mapped correctly (from the root).

project/dir/subdir/main_dir/script1.py:

```
from dir.subdir.other_dir.script2 import *  //also doesn't give errors
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution where you can skip the parent directories while importing (and don't have have to change anything in your script going from a Pycharm execution to a manual execution):

```
from script2 import *
```

works when you set the PYTHONPATH variable before running your script, e.g. like this in Windows:

```
set PYTHONPATH=../other_dir && python script1.py
```

for Linux (bash) it is:

```
PYTHONPATH=../other_dir python script1.py
```

I believe this is also what PyCharm does upon execution: adding the according folders to the PYTHONPATH.